# Add pasword on PDF using FPD on Download

Tags: php, fpdf

The output of my fpdf is download. an I want to automatically add a password on it before you can view the pdf.

```
$pdf->Output('C:\Users\User1\Desktop\filename.pdf','D');
```

Comment: Anything you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Already got the answer. it's `fpdf_protection`  thanks, anyways!